# Get date part alone from the datetime (datatype in entity) and display in grid

Tags: linq

i wanted to display only the date using linq
my coding is

```
    var xyz = from xy in entity.TrainingDetails
                      join ede in entity.EmployeeDetails
                      on xy.TrainerId equals ede.id
                      join lmn in entity.Topics
                      on xy.TopicId equals lmn.id
                      where (xy.TrainerId == ede.id)
                      where (xy.TopicId == lmn.id)
                      select new
                      {
                          EmployeeId = ede.EmployeeId,
                          Trainer = ede.FirstName + ede.MiddleName + ede.LastName,
                          SINo = xy.Id,
                          TrainingDate = xy.TrainingDate,
                          StartTime = xy.StartTime,
                          EndTime = xy.EndTime
                      };
```

This is working.In my output the date is displayed in **12-04-2013 00:00:00**
Here i want only `12-04-2013`.
I tried

```
    TrainingDate = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",xy.TrainingDate),
    TrainingDate = xy.TrainingDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
    TrainingDate =xy.TrainingDate.ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    TrainingDate =xy.TrainingDate .Date
```

all these but still dnt get.

Answer (score 0):

```
      var xyz = from xy in entity.TrainingDetails.AsEnumerable()
                  join ede in entity.EmployeeDetails
                  on xy.TrainerId equals ede.id
                  join lmn in entity.Topics
                  on xy.TopicId equals lmn.id
                  where (xy.TrainerId == ede.id)
                  where (xy.TopicId == lmn.id)
                  select new
                  {
                      EmployeeId = ede.EmployeeId,
                      Trainer = ede.FirstName + ede.MiddleName + ede.LastName,
                      SINo = xy.Id,
                      TrainingDate = xy.TrainingDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                      StartTime = xy.StartTime,
                      EndTime = xy.EndTime
                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Nullable type (i.e., DateTime? or DateTimeOffset?).
• Use the static field DateTime.MinValue or DateTimeOffset.MinValue (the default
values for these types)

You should write your code like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<TrainingDetailItem> SelectAll()
    {
          List<TrainingDetailItem> gridRowItemsList = null;

          using (var context = new entities())
          {


                 gridRowItemsList = (from table in context.table
                                     select new GridRowItem
                                     {

                                     }).OrderByDescending(item => item.Id).ToList();
          }

   }

and in models create class TrainingDetailItem and set time like this:

public DateTime? TrainingDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndTimeDate { get; set; }
```